# `catalina.sh start` (to start tomcat) just hangs

Tags: tomcat6, catalina

I have `tomcat6.0.37` and I am trying to start it by running `catalina.sh` and it just hangs there for more than 30 mins. I couldn't got `localhost:8080/myapp` either.

Does anyone know what happened?

```
$ ./catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: An older version 1.1.24 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat recommends version greater than 1.1.27
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.24 using APR version 1.4.6.
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized with version OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 331 ms
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:47 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:48 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:48 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Jul 25, 2013 10:49:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 447 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to set a different random number generator by modifying / setting JAVA_OPS.

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

There are some issues with the original one, which causes Tomcat to wait....

Answer (score 0):

your os uses 8080 so please change it to any different port it will be solved